# Curve text in Microsoft Word for Mac 2011

Tags: ms-office

How can I make my text follow a curve or arch shape in Microsoft Word for Mac 2011?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This site is organized differently than traditional forum sites. In this Q&A format, we need to only have one question per question. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask that separately using the Ask Question link at the top right of any page. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: My first response was to think that WordArt is in the Insert menu just like it has been since at least the early 90s. But they *really* hid the features for it in this latest edition of Word.

Answer (score 4):

Insert -> WordArt, then Format tab appears.

Click Review tab.

Click Format tab again.

Now, click Effects button ("A"), and select "Transform" from the drop-down menu.

The arch, wavy lines, and other formats are shown under the "Warp" section on the ribbon.

Answer (score 3):

In Office 11 (Mac) at the top, go to VIEW and make sure "Standard" is selected under "Toolbars". Go to *Insert → WordArt*. Type in your text in the wordart box. Hit the "Format" button, right next to "Home". One of your new selections under "Text Styles" should be "Effects". Click on *Effects* and select the last selection, "Transform".

You should have a whole selection of options including curving text up or down, and making circles. You can edit the curvature by pulling on the text box handles, up and down, and on the corners. You can rotate the text box by clicking and holding on the long "knob" on the text box.

Comment: there's nothing called "Text Styles" there.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a graphic showing how to do this in Word 2011 for Mac:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Still a little hidden, but here's one way to get there . . .

Start a text box
Select INSERT and then Word Art
Choose your Word Art style and write your phrase
Highlight it
Go to the TOOLBOX section QUICK STYLES AND EFFECTS and choose the abc option

Then play with the magenta square on the text box and the size of the text box (as well as the rotate text box) to get the curve you want

A little harder than on a PC but everything else is worth this minor hassle.